# C/C++ code or Bash script to sign jar files

Tags: jar, jarsigner

Is there C/C++ code or a Bash script that can sign Java .jar files without using a JVM?
Such code might be useful for embedded applications that serve a jar file with a small HTTP server, or other situations where a jar file might need to be edited and re-signed programmatically but there is insufficient storage space for a JVM.

Does anyone need this type of Javaless jarsigner?

Comment: I would really like this as an added layer for license verification. If I could call some object from one of our native binaries to validate the calling java program, it would be a nice layer of extra tamper-detection.